# Map and Zip SQL query result to create grouped data structure

Tags: elixir, ecto

I have a data structure from `SQL.query(Repo...)` as such:

`IO.inspect results.columns`:

```
["tour_id", "name", "year", "num_shows", "num_cities", "num_festivals", "num_countries"]
```

and the actual rows, `IO.inspect results.rows`:

```
[
  [5, "tour", 2022, 13, 10, 4, 2],
  [1, "asia", 2018, 4, 4, 3, 3],
  [2, "north america", 2018, 39, 17, 2, 2],
  [3, "europe", 2018, 13, 12, 9, 10],
  [4, "las vegas shows", 2018, 3, 1, 0, 1]
]
```

I am struggling to do something like `Enum.zip` where the result would be:

```
[
 [ tour_id: 5, name: "tour", year: 2022, num_shows: 13, ....],
 [ tour_id: 1, name: "asia", year: 2018, num_shows: 4, ....],
]
```

Ultimately, I want to do a `group_by` based on `year`:

```
2018: [
        [ tour_id: 1, name: "asia", year: 2018, num_shows: 4, ....],
        [ tour_id: 3, name: "europe", year: 2018, num_shows: 13, ....],
      ],
2022: [ ... ]
```

Or, however else one may suggest it should be formatted. I thought converting the rows and columns to keyword lists would do the trick, and then I can do the `group_by`.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a keyword list of column name -> row value at the end, the first step would be to convert the column names to atoms:

```
columns =
  ["tour_id", "name", "year", "num_shows", "num_cities", "num_festivals", "num_countries"]
  |> Enum.map(&String.to_atom/1)
```

Then you can map over the rows and zip each one with the columns:

```
rows = [
  [5, "tour", 2022, 13, 10, 4, 2],
  [1, "asia", 2018, 4, 4, 3, 3],
  [2, "north america", 2018, 39, 17, 2, 2],
  [3, "europe", 2018, 13, 12, 9, 10],
  [4, "las vegas shows", 2018, 3, 1, 0, 1]
]

zipped = for row <- rows, do: Enum.zip(columns, row)

IO.inspect(zipped)
```

```
[
  [
    tour_id: 5,
    name: "tour",
    year: 2022,
    num_shows: 13,
    num_cities: 10,
    num_festivals: 4,
    num_countries: 2
  ],
  [
    tour_id: 1,
    name: "asia",
    year: 2018,
    num_shows: 4,
    num_cities: 4,
    num_festivals: 3,
    num_countries: 3
  ],
  [
    tour_id: 2,
    name: "north america",
    year: 2018,
    num_shows: 39,
    num_cities: 17,
    num_festivals: 2,
    num_countries: 2
  ],
  [
    tour_id: 3,
    name: "europe",
    year: 2018,
    num_shows: 13,
    num_cities: 12,
    num_festivals: 9,
    num_countries: 10
  ],
  [
    tour_id: 4,
    name: "las vegas shows",
    year: 2018,
    num_shows: 3,
    num_cities: 1,
    num_festivals: 0,
    num_countries: 1
  ]
]
```

And finally group by the year:

```
IO.inspect(Enum.group_by(zipped, fn row -> row[:year] end))
```

```
%{
  2018 => [
    [
      tour_id: 1,
      name: "asia",
      year: 2018,
      num_shows: 4,
      num_cities: 4,
      num_festivals: 3,
      num_countries: 3
    ],
    [
      tour_id: 2,
      name: "north america",
      year: 2018,
      num_shows: 39,
      num_cities: 17,
      num_festivals: 2,
      num_countries: 2
    ],
    [
      tour_id: 3,
      name: "europe",
      year: 2018,
      num_shows: 13,
      num_cities: 12,
      num_festivals: 9,
      num_countries: 10
    ],
    [
      tour_id: 4,
      name: "las vegas shows",
      year: 2018,
      num_shows: 3,
      num_cities: 1,
      num_festivals: 0,
      num_countries: 1
    ]
  ],
  2022 => [
    [
      tour_id: 5,
      name: "tour",
      year: 2022,
      num_shows: 13,
      num_cities: 10,
      num_festivals: 4,
      num_countries: 2
    ]
  ]
}
```

Comment: wow. I was missing the `to_atom`. This makes a lot of sense - thank you! The order when `group_by` occurs loses the original (where 2022 should be prior to 2018, as it's `DESC` from db). Should I just sort on iteration?

Comment: Maps is Elixir are unordered. In this case it's printed in ascending order but that's not guaranteed. You do need to sort it after the group_by which will turn it into a list and then you can iterate over it with a guaranteed order.

Comment: That's awesome - I did `Enum.sort(grouped_by_year, :desc)` and didn't have to change the iteration - worked just like that! Thank you so much!

Comment: Yep, calling `Enum.sort` on a map gives a sorted list of tuples and when you iterate over it, it yields tuples just like a map does.